# Remove Boot Error

Tags: systemctl

Because of its intended usage, I'm trying to lock down my Raspberry Pi into a read only. I'm [using this script](https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/), though it is for an older distro.

Not unexpectedly, I'm getting an error during boot:

```
Failed to start set console font and keymap
see 'systemctl status console-setup.service' for details.
```

The system doesn't appear to work well in read only mode, but it doesn't look like it'll be a problem. A lot of the help on the topic is centered around solving the issue, but I don't think I'll be able to solve it in my case.

Is this something vital? Is there a way to fix it in my special case, and if not remove the error from showing up?